# Suggested edit with "improved grammar" that actually makes everything worse

Tags: discussion, editing

[This suggested edit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/57698) just got approved:

[image: screenshot]

Remember: Right side is the new version!

Seriously? That's close to vandalism, it does not make sense at all. Can we revert that?

**And a request to all:** please be more careful when suggesting and reviewing edits. I often see edits where one or two minor spelling or formatting mistakes are corrected but the rest of the post is a horrible mess. This is wasting the time of reviewers and should not be rewarded IMHO. As a reviewer, I usually reject or if possible, improve these edits.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as this is not a question... Just kidding vote up ;)

Comment: If people were self aware of their lack of actual skill in English they wouldn't vandalize post in edits. But I guess we all come from different countries and some may have been taught a different version of English than we were, keep that in mind.

Comment: @JulienLachal yes, that's a good point. It is something I've noticed more and more recently is that the users of this site are from countries all over the world, largely (reference?) from countries where English is not their first language. This means that when they make a "grammar" edit on a post, it may actually be stylistic, personal choice or just slightly better than it was before, but none of those reasons would make it viable to someone with fluent English

Comment: Also while we're at it, why is it a trend that the three answers on that question all just say "you can do it with this code: xxx" with no explanation or what they're trying to show? They've all received a downvote for being low quality from me. Rant over!

Comment: @JulienLachal People being taught a "different version of English" need to understand that the version they were taught is incorrect! English has rules, and regional differences in spelling shouldn't account for someone's lack of proper usage. Changing "will" to "who" is simply not correct no matter what "version" of English you know.

Comment: @pspahn but then we can't really blame them for not mastering English. I'm totally agree (see what I did there?) that they should be self-aware of this, but what can you do?

Comment: I'm wondering how this got approved by 2/3.